# Signal R NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an error in the start of an application (Console Application) .NET Core 3.1.

First
I have a WebAPI .NET Core 3.1 that implements a "Hub" class "ChatWeb" passing the / chatWeb route as an endPoint.

In my console application (.Net Core 3.1 and NuGet - Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 5.0.0) I have the following code:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("https://localhost:55587/chatWeb").WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();
        connection.StartAsync().Wait();
        connection.InvokeCoreAsync("EnviarMensagem", args: new[] { "Teste", "mensagem teste" });
        connection.On("RecebendoMensagem", (string nome, string msg) => 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(nome + ":" + msg);
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

When the application starts it breaks on the HubConnectionBuilder line with the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Either add System.Text.Encodings.Web to your project, or update your app to net5.0, or downgrade SignalR to 3.1, or wait for a future patch where the problem package (System.Text.Json 5.0) is fixed.

Comment: @Brennan Perfectly, is work for me. Thank You!